# Flutter create a stream service that sends a URL to a widget through streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a music player that works just fine, but I want to put the music player widget inside a StreamBuilder and have a string that's the url of the music to be played in the stream and pass that url into the constructor of the music player.
So the music player content changes whenever that url stream changes.

My simple musicplayerurlservice class:

```
class MusicPlayerURLService {
  String url = '';

  String get(){
    return url;
  }

  void set(String newUrl) {
    url = newUrl;
  }
}
```

The constructor of the music player widget:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: MusicPlayerURLService().get(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                var user = snapshot.data;
                if (user == null) {
                  return Container(width: 20);
                }
                return MusicPlayer(url: snapshot.data.url);
              }
              return Container(width: 20);
            }),
```

Then in another view i'll have a button that calls the set method in the MusicPlayerURLService and sets a new URL.

At the moment the stream builder throws and error because the get method in the url service isnt a stream.

I'm struggling to think of general ideas to solve this. Could I use a provider somehow?

EDIT

The urls will come from buttons like this one:

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => MusicPlayerURLService().set("songOneUrl"),
  child: Text("Play Song One"),
)
```

Comment: Where are you getting these URLs from?

Comment: Is it showing you as a Future?

Comment: @AbirAhsan `get()` doesn't return a future, it returns a string. The OP posted that code.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore the urls will come from button widgets when clicked, i've put an example code in the post

Comment: Why are you creating new `MusicPlayerURLService` objects every time you use one of its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to create your own `Stream` to accomplish this. The best method for this case would likely be to use a `StreamController`.

You should add a `StreamController` as a part of your `MusicPlayerURLService` and instantiate it in the constructor. When setting a new URL, you should tell the controller to add it to your stream as well. And to get the stream from the `StreamController`, make a new method that returns the `controller.stream`.

Ex.

```dart
class MusicPlayerURLService {
  String url = '';
  StreamController<String> controller;

  MusicPlayerURLService() {
    controller = StreamController();
    controller.add(url);
  }

  String get(){
    return url;
  }

  Stream<String> getStream() {//Use this in your StreamBuilder
    return controller.stream;
  }

  void set(String newUrl) {
    url = newUrl;
    controller.add(url);
  }
}
```

This method involves passing the *same* `MusicPlayerURLService` object to everywhere it needs be used. You might be able to get away with making the necessary parts static as shown here:

```dart
class MusicPlayerURLService {
  static StreamController<String> controller = StreamController();

  static Stream<String> getStream() {//Use this in your StreamBuilder
    return controller.stream;
  }

  static void set(String newUrl) {
    controller.add(newUrl);
  }
}
```

or you could use the Provider package to make a single instance of the object available throughout the tree if you think it's necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Having a play around with this now

Comment: I went for a Streamprovider<String>.value (value: MusicPlayerURLService.getStream(), child: MusicPlayer) then inside the music player in the build method: String url = Provider.of<String>(context); But when i make a text widget in the music player displaying the url nothing is coming through

Comment: @MikaelWills add a listener to your stream and print the values to check that you're using it correctly.

Comment: Added a listener in the service class and it's working and printing out the url that comes through. 

url input:
 FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => MusicPlayerURLService().set("songOneUrl"),
                child: whiteText("Play Song One"),
 ),

Comment: Just tried a consumer and that's not picking up the stream value in the widget tree either

Consumer<String>(
            builder: (context, url, child) {
              return whiteText("url: $url");
            },
          ),

Comment: @MikaelWills Are you using the static or object-based method? Your `onPressed` is inconsistent with the `Stream`. It's not necessary to use provider if you're using the static method and it adds complexity.

Comment: Oh that kinda flew over my head, not sure what that means, i wanna say it's static? I'm not displaying an object from a class i'm just displaying a string

Comment: @MikaelWills You can read about static variables and methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26822953). It's an important part of object-oriented programming and not related to what you're displaying. It also means that you never need to create a class instance so the methods are always accessed with `MusicPlayerURLService`(note: *no* parentheses).

Comment: I appreciate the help, I will definitely soak up more general theory in due course, but this isn't really helping with my immediate problem. I feel like i'm soo close its just a matter of couple extra lines i'll look over and understand. for example i've scoured more and more forums and after a post it might of looked like I just needed to add .toString() to the end of the provider value. And i've also tried to use a get_it locator to try and achieve it but with no success. All I need is for someone to say, oh no you just use a (provider/get_it/stream or something) with this line of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219010/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-mikael-wills).

Comment: It works! Apologies for sounding rude. I implemented the static approach but for some reason I thought I had to access the stream value through a provider or another service rather than directly through the stream, which sounds stupid now that I think of it. Thank you for having patience!